# Proper SSL Usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have read that you should use SSL not just when the user is logged in, but for the entire time the user is logged in.  It read, "Many web sites log in via SSL and redirect back to HTTP after you’re logged in, which is absolutely the wrong thing to do."  I think they're talking about session hijacking.

Ref.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Is this correct?  If so, why doesn't stack exchange have me in SSL right now?

Comment: I think the idea for using SSL for the entire time you are logged in is relatively new.  The idea has stemmed from the fact that there is little overhead cost with keeping user's connected via SSL the entire time compared to the past when the overhead would have been detrimental to performance.

Comment: So is it a real threat to fail to use SSL when a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SSL every time you send sensitive information over a network like passwords, credit card information, your bank account, ...

> Is it really necessary to always use SSL when a user is logged in?

Not always however it is pretty easy these days to steal someone's session cookie over an unencrypted wireless network. If someone steals my cookie and posts nonsens on Stack Overflow it's probably not going to impact my life. Facebook and Twitter (spying governments) can be a different story.